# scons : src and include dirs

Tags: python, scons

can someone give a scons config file which allows the following structure

```
toplevel/
        /src - .cc files
        /include .h files
```

at top level I want the o and final exe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
env=Environment(CPPPATH='/usr/include/glib-2.0/:/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include:include',
                CPPDEFINES=[],
                LIBS=['glib-2.0']) 

if ARGUMENTS.get('debug', 0):
    env.Append(CCFLAGS = ' -g')

env.Program('template', Glob('src/*.cc'))
```

Worked a treat. Thanks.

Comment: How do we make the object files(*.o) go into a newly created folder called obj

Answer (score 7):

Here is one example of Sconscript file

```
env=Environment(CPPPATH='/usr/include/glib-2.0/:/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include:inc',
                CPPDEFINES=[],
                LIBS=['glib-2.0']) 
env.Program('runme', Glob('src/*.c'))
```

(The environment line is not really necessary for the example, but I have it to include the non standard glib header path and left it there so you can get the idea how to add extra includes and defines)

The source files are in src directory and header files in inc directory. You run scons from the base directory and the output file is also generated in the same directory.

Answer (score 5):

This question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279860/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279860/how-do-i-get-projects-to-place-their-build-output-into-the-same-directory-with) 
gives a pretty flexible scons skeleton which should serve your needs with a few tweaks to the path variables.

Comment: I think this answer is too difficult for most people new to scons. VariantDir? (for example) and assumes knowledge of Python.

Comment: Your assumption is correct Richard. I have no idea what that config file does but I think I managed to pull something useful from it.